# Calculating probabilities for uniform distributions

Tags: statistics

Let X have a uniform distribution on the interval $[0, 10]$. Find $P(X(X + 10) > 11)$

I know that uniform distribution will have a PDF= $1/b-a$ for $x=(a,b)=[0,10]$, and $0$ everywhere else. However I am unsure how to use this information to calculate $P[X]$, and  consequently $ P(X(X + 10) > 11)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X(X + 10) > 11$ iff $1\le X\le 10$ . This is so because $1$ and $-11$ are the solutions of the quadratic equation $$x^2+10x-11=0.$$ Below $-11$ and above $1 \,\,$ $x(x + 10) \ge 11$.

$X$, however, cannot take values below zero and above $10$. So the only possibility is if $1\le X\le 10$, the event  whose probability is $$\frac9{10}=\int_1^{10}f_X(x)\ dx=\frac1{10}\int_1^{10}\ dx.$$.

Comment: that is all that is needed for this? the information about it being a uniform distribution or the probability density function are not needed for the solution?

Comment: $\frac9{10}$ is the area under the probability density function between $1$ and $10$. The pdf of the uniform distribution over $[0,10]$ is $\frac1{10}$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: I edited my answer for your convenience.